# wxNotebook active page highlighting

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I develop wxwidget app in windows. I want to know is there any way to change the colour of current active tab so that highlight current opened page.? I do not want to change the colour of page, but only tab area .I am using wxNotebook.

Comment: I see this question with down-votes and not a single comment. It's not kind to down-vote without any hint. So, I will provide it: Please, read [SO: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [SO: Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Considering these will improve the chance to get a valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

wxWidgets uses native widgets and the selection highlight of the current notebook tab in the native control is determined by the current theme, as selected by the user, and there is no way to change it.

If you need custom appearance for your notebook tabs, you might want to have a look at [wxAuiNotebook](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_aui_notebook.html) which allows to customize its appearance in a variety of ways.